# Cloud Messaging using GCM

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, pushbots

I am trying Notifications task using Pushbots. I was follow what are the steps to do in Android Manifest file. My device registered successfully but messages not sent to my device. Its Checking on Pushbots sand box I got Notification deilvery failed to 1 devices.and in my android studio console AndroidManifest.xml missing required permission: android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS.....

Comment: Which version of Google Play Services are you running? This permission seems to have been a requirement of older Google Play Services versions.

Comment: I am using Pushbots we are creating Server Id and Sender Id from Google  Play Servises only

Comment: I see, but the client requires Google Play Services in order to receive messages. Which version are you running on the client?

Comment: I am Using compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.pushbots:pushbots-lib:2.0.13@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0', I am new to Android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this page (step 2): https://pushbots.com/developer/docs/android-sdk-integration

Alter your `AndroidManifest.xml` file, and add the following permissions:

```
<!-- GCM connects to Google Services. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<permission android:name="com.example.sampleapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.sampleapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<!-- This app has permission to register and receive dataf message. -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
```

Comment: Thanks for it. I already use this code from : https://pushbots.com/developer/docs/android-sdk-integration

Comment: Thanks... Actually I want to send Server end notifications to Mobile app.

Comment: Actually I want to send Server end notifications to Mobile app. My server end code is developed by using Spring and From my web application I want to send Notification to Mobile when any Particular record is updated. This impact is known to updated record related user through notification. I am new to android. So in case you have any Idea Please share to me Thanks in Advance....